# English Translation of Yaska's Nirukta

Tags: scripture, translation-request, nirukta

Is online English Translation of Yaska's Nirukta available ? If yes please provide .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it [here](https://archive.org/details/nighantuniruktao00yaskuoft/page/n343/mode/2up) . In starting sanskrit text is present , however the link I sent directly starts from english translation